# What's the life time of the string object passed into std::runtime_error's ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, standards, object-lifetime

According to [cppreferences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), `explicit runtime_error( const std::string& what_arg );` won't copy `what_arg`'s content.

Can I safely pass a temporary string object into `std::runtime_error`'s `ctor`?

For example:

```
std::string GetATempString(const char* msg)
{
    return { msg };
}

int main()
{
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error(GetATempString("Hello"));
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) 
    {
            e.what(); // Is it guaranteed that "Hello" would be returned safely?
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it say the content is not copied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand.  `std::runtime_error` always copies the string into a reference-counted copy-on-write internal buffer, because it may not throw an exception later when copying.

Comment: "reference-counted copy-on-write" - why? When is the string modified?